# Redirecting System.setout back to standard output

Tags: java, redirectstandardoutput

`System.setout` redirects the standard output. For instance,

```
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("file.txt");
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(f));
```

Every `System.out.print` will write in the file. My question is, how to set the output back to the standard once this has been done?

Comment: You need a reference to the original stream, for example PrintStream ps = System.out;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just save it and restore it:

```
final PrintStream oldStdout = System.out;
System.setOut(newStdout);
// ...
System.setOut(oldStdout);
```